# Dbus-API - acquire service linking error in c /Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dbus

I am trying to compile and run an example for C-DBUS. Here is my DBUS-Server.

```
#include <dbus/dbus.h>

/** How to compile dbus- gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs dbus-1` dbus_server.c -o dbus_server.out **/
int main()
{

  DBusError error;
  DBusConnection *conn;

  /** Initialize the bus.. **/
  dbus_error_init(&error);

  /** Get the system bus...........**/
  conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM,&error);

  if( !conn)
   {
      printf("ERROR................................in getting bus...\r\n");

      return -1;  


    }


  /** acquire service **/


  dbus_bus_acquire_service(conn, "org.shreyas.tune",0,&error);


  if( dbus_error_is_set(&error))
  {
     dbus_connection_disconnect(conn);  
     printf("Disconnect bus... some problem in acquiring service..\r\n");
     return -1;  
  }

  /** Let's send a signal **/

  DBusMessage *msg;
  DBusMessageIter iter;

  /** My signal name is SJ_FIRST_EXAMPLE **/
  msg = dbus_message_new_signal("org/shreyas/tune/attr","org.shreyas.tune.attr","SJ_FIRST_EXAMPLE");

  /** Let fill the payload now **/

  dbus_message_iter_init(msg,&iter);
  dbus_message_iter_append_string(&iter,"This is my first example");

  /** send the message **/

  if(!dbus_connection_send( conn, msg,NULL) )
  {
     printf("Error in sending the message\r\n");
     return -1;  
  }

  dbus_message_unref(msg);

  dbus_connection_flush(conn);




  return 0; 




}
```

```
$gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs dbus-1` dbus_server.c -o dbus_server.out
dbus_server.c: In function ‘main’:
dbus_server.c:19:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
dbus_server.c:35:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
dbus_server.c:56:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccGFwJyC.o: In function `main':
dbus_server.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_acquire_service'
dbus_server.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_disconnect'
dbus_server.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_append_string'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to resolve the linking error here? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags dbus-1` dbus-server.c `pkg-config --libs dbus-1` -o dbus-server.out
```

The cflags and libs go to the compiler and linker respectively. For some reason gcc needs the cflags before the .c file and the libs after it in two separate `pkg-config` calls.

Also try using a makefile or a script so you don't have to type that whole mess every time you recompile.

Answer (score 0):

JB0x2D1’s answer is correct for solving your linking problem.

It is highly recommended that you use a D-Bus library *other* than libdbus, however, as libdbus is fiddly to use correctly. If possible, use [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) or [QtDBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) instead, as they are much higher-level bindings which are easier to use. If you need a lower-level binding, [sd-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) is more modern than libdbus.